# How to create cross domain calls with jquery and MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 sites. 
Website Original.com is a standard HTML/ jquery created site.
Website Request.com is a MVC 4 site.

I would like to request a partial view from Original.com to Request.com like:

$.ajax({

```
    type:"GET",
    beforeSend: function (request)
    {
        request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://request.com");
    },

    crossDomain: true,
    url: "http://request.com/Settings/User/Test/123"),
    success: function (data) {
        self.container("#output").html(data);
    }
});
```

In my request.com I have added the following:

```
        AllowCrossSiteHtmlAttribute.SetDefaultCrossSiteUrl("http://original.com");
```

the partial view looks like

```
    [AllowCrossSiteHtmlAttribute()]
    public PartialViewResult Test(string id){
        var model = new TestModel(id);
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

what ever I tried, I always ended up with an error.
Does somebody knows how to set the settings on both sites?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this? I want to do something very similar in my project.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a look at CORS which is Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. [This website](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) explains in detail how to implement CORS in ASP.NET MVC4.